# How to calculate the maximum and minimum values for a piecewise function?

Tags: calculus, functions, solution-verification, maxima-minima

I was trying to calculate the maximum and minimum for this function:

$f(x) = \begin{cases}
    \begin{aligned}
        x + 2, & \quad \text{if } -1 \leq x < 0
    \end{aligned} \\
    \begin{aligned}
        1, & \quad \text{if } x = 0
    \end{aligned} \\
    \begin{aligned}
        \frac{x}{2}, & \quad \text{if } 0 < x \leq 1
    \end{aligned}
\end{cases}$

I was able to do it using calculus as follows:

We can differentiate f(x) for $−1\leq x<0$ (except end point i.e. -1) and $0<x\leq 1$ (except end point i.e. 1) as it is continuous. But even after differentiation, we will $f ' (x) = 1$ or $\frac{1}{2}$ for $(x+2)$ and $\frac{x}{2}$ respectively, and thus no critical points can be obtained to check for maximum and minimum.

Additionally, critical points are the points where $f ' (x)$ is undefined and since $f (x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, we can take $x=0$ as a critical point. But $f ' (x)$ doesn't change the sign while passing through $x=0$ i.e. slope is positive on either side of $x=0$. So $x=0$ has neither maximum nor minimum. In conclusion, $f(x)$ has neither maximum nor minimum.

I felt if these cases could be combined into 1, it would be easier to calculate as only 1 derivative can be taken and equated to 0 to obtain critical points and then we can proceed towards confirming maximum or minimum or neither at those critical points.

Comment: There is not going to be a “nice” function which behaves like this. But a piece-wise function is a perfectly fine function, why do you want something else?

Comment: I was trying to calculate the maximum and minimum for this function. I was able to do it using calculus but I had to look for 3 cases separately. I just felt if these cases could be combined into 1, it would be easier to calculate as only 1 derivative can be taken and equated to 0 to obtain critical points and then we can proceed towards confirming maximum or minimum or neither at those critical points.
I agree that piece-wise function is perfectly fine in itself.

Comment: @Pythagoras by drawing the graph, you can locate the local or global maximum and minimum easily.

Comment: @Pythagoras Your piece-wise function $f$ is not even continuous to apply differentiation, and "doing calculus" on each piece of the function to find global maxima/minima is a very careful business. I suggest you to carefully look at your function before taking derivatives, maybe checking its graph will give you the information you need.

Comment: @Edd, I agree that f(x) is not continuous at x=0  and thus, f(x) is not differentiable at x=0. However, we can differentiate f(x)  for −1≤x<0 (except end point i.e. -1) and 0<x≤1 (except end point i.e. 1) as it is continuous. But even after differentiation, we will f ' (x) = 1 or 1/2 for (x+2) and (x/2) respectively, and thus no critical points can be obtained to check for maximum and minimum.

Comment: @Edd Additionally, critical points are the points where f ' (x) is undefined and since f (x) is not differentiable at x=0, we can take x=0 as a critical point. But f ' (x) doesn't change the sign while passing through x=0 i.e. slope is positive on either side of x=0. So x=0 has neither maximum nor minimum. In conclusion, f(x) has neither maximum nor minimum. I think this can be an appropriate answer using calculus. What do you think?

Comment: @Pythagoras $x = 0$ is neither a local maximum nor minimum, but that is unrelated to the values of $f'$ (where it's defined). That's always the case at discontinuity points, you can't draw conclusions at $x = 0$ using the local behavior of the derivative because the function itself has a local behavior totally independent of its value at $x = 0$ due to jumps. Also, you have to take into account the endpoints of the interval of definition when you're searching for maxima/minima, which in this case they don't contribute as well.

Comment: @Pythagoras Your function does not have global maxima/minima indeed, but your analysis of derivatives at each side of $x = 0$, along with the discontinuity at $x = 0,$ is not enough to conclude this. For example, the fact that $f'$ never vanishes in $(-1,0)$ doesn't discard the possibility for a maximum or minimum value attained at $x = -1$ (which is neither in this case) or at $x = 0.$ If I were to redefine $f(0) = 2,$ $f$ would suddenly have a maximum undetectable by looking at derivatives around $x = 0.$

Comment: @Edd I agree with your comment regarding x=0. Regarding endpoints, they should be included in the case of absolute maxima and minima.  For this question, why do you think the endpoints of the interval i.e. x=1 and x=-1 don't contribute to maximum and minimum? Could you elaborate upon your answer?

Comment: @Pythagoras A quick analysis of $f$ would be: $x = 0$ is neither a local maximum nor minimum (easily checked), so we forget about this point. Since $f$ takes larger values on $[-1,0)$ compared to $(0,1]$, and $f$ is continuous and increasing in $[-1,0)$ (here you can use derivatives for example), $f$ does not attain a maximum. Since $f$ is also continuous and increasing in $(0,1],$ it does not attain a minimum either. Now, if you ask about *local* maxima/minima, $f$ has a local minimum at $x = -1,$ and a local maximum at $x = 1.$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147721/discussion-between-pythagoras-and-edd).